# IE9 - CKEdtor is being disabled after save when using knockout js

Tags: knockout.js, ckeditor

I don't actualy know how to elaborate on this bug, but here is how it goes:
I'm using CKEditor for multiple textareas on the same screen using knockout js "foreach".

The CKEditor is implemented along with knockout js like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.CKEDITOR = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var ckEditorValue = valueAccessor();
        var id = $(element).attr('id');
        var allBindings = allBindings();
        var options = allBindings.EditorOptions;
        var visible = (typeof allBindings.visible == 'undefined' ? true : allBindings.visible);
        id = (typeof allBindings.id == 'undefined' ? id : allBindings.id);

        if (!visible || id == '') {
            $(element).hide();
            return;
        }

        $(element).attr('id', id).addClass("orb-ckeditor");

        var ignoreChanges = false;

        var defaultConfig = {};
        defaultConfig.toolbar = [
                                    ["Undo", "Redo"],
                                    ["Bold", "Italic", "Underline", "Strike", "RemoveFormat", "-", "TextColor"],
                                    ["NumberedList", "BulletedList", "Outdent", "Indent"],
                                    ["JustifyLeft", "JustifyCenter", "JustifyRight", "JustifyBlock"],
                                    ["Link", "Unlink"]
                                ];
        defaultConfig.defaultLanguage = 'en';
        defaultConfig.removePlugins = 'resize, wordcount, elementspath, magicline';
        defaultConfig.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;

        defaultConfig.on = {
            change: function () {
                ignoreChanges = true;
                ckEditorValue(instance.getData());
                ignoreChanges = false;
            }
        };
        $.extend(defaultConfig, options);
        var instance = CKEDITOR.replace(id, defaultConfig);

        instance.setData(ckEditorValue());

        ckEditorValue.subscribe(function (newValue) {
            if (!ignoreChanges) {
                instance.setData(newValue);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<div class="quiz-settings" data-bind="foreach: items">
    <textarea data-bind="CKEDITOR: PropertyObjectValue, visible: (PropertyType == 'MULTILINES' || PropertyType == 'EMAIL'), id: 'txtProp' + PropertyID"></textarea>
</div>
```

I'm saving the data using an AJAX call and on the `success` method I'm re-binding the data to the editors.
It works fine in Chrome but in IE9 the editor is disabled after the save action when I click in it to edit but when I click on the font color button that opens the color palette the editor is enabled again

I have no idea why this happens or how to fix it...

Comment: You say that it works in Chrome but fails in IE9, what happens in other browsers? Firefox, IE11?

Comment: Didn't check... I actually need it only for IE9 because this is the browser we use where I work...

Comment: Well, the rest of the world has moved forward and IE9 is only a bad memory. Hopefully you'll be able to find someone else that still uses it.

Comment: Tell me about it. I don't know why to use any IE in the first place, but it is not up to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved it :-)

I've aaded these lines in the `ko.bindingHandlers.CKEDITOR`

```
// Destroy instance if exist
if (CKEDITOR.instances[id]) {
    CKEDITOR.instances[id].destroy();
}
```

like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.CKEDITOR = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var ckEditorValue = valueAccessor();
        var id = $(element).attr('id');
        var allBindings = allBindings();
        var options = allBindings.EditorOptions;
        var visible = (typeof allBindings.visible == 'undefined' ? true : allBindings.visible);
        id = (typeof allBindings.id == 'undefined' ? id : allBindings.id);

        if (!visible || id == '') {
            $(element).hide();
            return;
        }

        $(element).attr('id', id).addClass("orb-ckeditor");

        var ignoreChanges = false;

        var defaultConfig = {};
        defaultConfig.toolbar = [
                                    ["Undo", "Redo"],
                                    ["Bold", "Italic", "Underline", "Strike", "RemoveFormat", "-", "TextColor"],
                                    ["NumberedList", "BulletedList", "Outdent", "Indent"],
                                    ["JustifyLeft", "JustifyCenter", "JustifyRight", "JustifyBlock"],
                                    ["Link", "Unlink"]
                                ];
        defaultConfig.defaultLanguage = 'en';
        defaultConfig.removePlugins = 'resize, wordcount, elementspath, magicline';
        defaultConfig.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;

        defaultConfig.on = {
            change: function () {
                ignoreChanges = true;
                ckEditorValue(instance.getData());
                ignoreChanges = false;
            }
        };
        $.extend(defaultConfig, options);

        // Destroy instance if exist
        if (CKEDITOR.instances[id])
            CKEDITOR.instances[id].destroy();

        // Create new instance
        var instance = CKEDITOR.replace(id, defaultConfig);

        instance.setData(ckEditorValue());

        ckEditorValue.subscribe(function (newValue) {
            if (!ignoreChanges)
                instance.setData(newValue);
        });
    }
};
```